# Quotations in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm learning dplyr and I'm confused about the use of quotation marks when specifying column names in some functions.

For example, when passing column names in the functions `select` and `arrange`, they should be unquoted, but when invoking the function `rename`, the arguments should be quoted. This is very confusing to me. Is there a reason for the inconsistency?
Also I tried to pass quoted arguments in `arrange` and it worked on my computer, but not on the DataCamp console (no errors occurred but the result was incorrect). How do you avoid this kind of situation? How do you know and remember when you should pass a quoted or unquoted argument?
(I know functions like `select_` exists. But to know that you should use `select_` instead of `select`, you should first know that `select` does not accept unquoted arguments. What I am asking for is a way to know all these without having to read documentations)

Edit:

Comment: Welcome to Non-standard evaluation. You can read about it here: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html. In `select` you can use strings, just have to use `all_of` or `any_of` to wrap them. It's all about the context of the variables (ex. `x` may be a variable in global env and a column within your dataframe; when it is unquoted the context is key).

Comment: The examples on the `?rename` help page do not use quotes. Recent updates to most dplyr functions try to get away from using quotes when working with column names. If you are seeing different behaviors it's probably because one of the machines have a different, older, version of `dplyr`. The `_` versions of the functions have been long deprecated. If you want to use strings now you are encouraged to use the `.data[[]]` pronoun. Some discussion here: https://tinyheero.github.io/2020/05/08/use-all-of-tidyverse.html

Comment: Alright. I'll check them out, although the non-standard evaluation doc seems a bit too hard for me.